# Regex - match any characters and allow any number of single spaces. Break match on a double space

Tags: regex

I am looking to create a match for the following:

- "Adam Lambert"
- "Mr. Adam Lambert"
- "adam@test.com"

But not match the following

- "Adam  Lambert"
- "Adam Lambert "

Rules:

- Any alphanumeric character should be matches
- A single space at any point should be matched.
- Any number of single spaces can be matches
- double spaces are not matched
- a single space at the end of a string is not matched

**EDIT**

I also need to match the following. Sorry I missed this.

```
name:((\w+(?:\S\w+)*|\s(?:\w+\S)*)\S)*
```

I need to match to:

- name:
- name:A
- name:Adam Lambert

The above regex matches from "name:Ad..." but it will not match "name:A"

Comment: Is "Adam Lambert" matched, or not?

Comment: `":"` in `"name:A"` is not an alphanumeric character or are you just matching `"name"` in those strings? Also, are you matching `" Adam Lambert"` in `"Mr. Adam Lambert"`? Further to @cigien's comment, will the real `"Adam Lambert"` step forward?

Comment: name: is explicit. We are looking for "name:" exactly but the characters after can change. So we could have "name:a", "name:mr. adam lambert" etc.

Comment: How do you explain that you are looking for `"name:"` considering that the colon is not an alphanumeric character? Also, please explain why `"Mr. Adam Lambert"` is a match? The references to `"Adam Lambert"` are because that string appears in both the "match" and "non-match" lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generalize a solution to matching a sequence of non-space characters followed by optional groups of non-space characters following a single space only, since your only hard criterion seems to be the number of spaces. For example:

```
^\S+(?: \S+)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:\S+(?:\s\S+)*|\s(?:\S+\s)*)\S$
```

Meaning:

- ^ start of the line
- (?: non-capturing group
- \S+ one or more non-whitespace characters
- (?:\s\S+)* zero or more groups of a single whitespace and one or more
  non-whitespace characters

or (|)

- ^ start of the line
- \s one whitespace character
- (?:\S+\s)* zero or more groups of non-whitespace characters and one whitespace character
- ) end non-capturing group

Finally one non whitespace character \S and the end of the line: $.

In your third example the @ won't be matched with \w but it will if you change it to \S (any non-whitespace character)

See it in action here: regexr.com/50lp2

edit: I can't type

Comment: Thank you! That is so close to what I need. I actually forgot to add one bit.. I have added to the requirement.

Comment: Sorry I made some edits to the post because I realized this if you change \w to \S all your requirements should be matched